# Error al añadir un segundo producto al carrito de compras PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Intento realizar un carrito de compras guardando los datos para cada sesión, hasta el momento he logrado imprimir el primer producto que elijo desde mi catálogo, pero no me es posible **agregar un segundo producto**.

Paso el ID del producto como parámetro por el **método GET**, al elegir el producto desde el `catalogo.php` pasa a la página `shoppingcar.php` con el `id` del producto pero no lo imprime en la página ni realiza las operaciones para obtener un total.

Les agradecería si me ayudan a encontrar el o los errores. Gracias de antemano

```
        <?php
            session_start();
            include("accion.php");
            include("verbindung.php");
            include("bar_sup.html");
            if(isset($_SESSION['car'])){
                if(isset($_GET['Produkt_ID'])){
                    $arreglo=$_SESSION['car'];
                    $encontro=false;
                    $numero=0;
                    for($i=0;$i<count($arreglo);$i++){
                        if($arreglo[$i]['produkt_id']==$_GET['Produkt_ID']){
                            $encontro=true;
                            $numero=$i;
                        }
                    }
                    if($encontro==true){
                        $arreglo[$numero]['menge']=$arreglo[$numero]['menge']+1;
                        $_SESSION['car']=$arreglo;

                    }else{
                        $name="";
                        $preis=0;
                        $foto="";
                        $produkt_query="SELECT Produkt_ID, Name, Preis, Produkttyp,Beschreibung,Foto FROM produkt WHERE Produkt_ID=". $_GET['Produkt_ID'];
                        $run_query=mysqli_query($verbindung,$produkt_query) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($verbindung));
                        while ($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($run_query)) {
                            $name=$rows['Name'];
                            $preis=$rows['Preis'];
                            $foto=$rows['Foto'];

                        }
                        $datosNuevos=array('produkt_id'=>$_GET['Produkt_ID'],
                        'name'=>$name,
                        'preis'=>$preis,
                        'foto'=>$foto,
                        'menge'=>1);

                        array_push($datosNuevos,$arreglo);
                        $_SESSION['Car']=$arreglo;

                    }
                }
            }else{
                if(isset($_GET['Produkt_ID'])){
                    $name="";
                    $preis=0;
                    $foto="";

                    $produkt_query="SELECT Produkt_ID, Name, Preis, Produkttyp,Beschreibung,Foto FROM produkt WHERE Produkt_ID=". $_GET['Produkt_ID'];
                    $run_query=mysqli_query($verbindung,$produkt_query) or die("Error: ". mysqli_error($verbindung));
                    while ($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($run_query)) {
                        $name=$rows['Name'];
                        $preis=$rows['Preis'];
                        $foto=$rows['Foto'];

                    }
                    $arreglo[]=array('produkt_id'=>$_GET['Produkt_ID'],
                    'name'=>$name,
                    'preis'=>$preis,
                    'foto'=>$foto,
                    'menge'=>1);
                    $_SESSION['car']=$arreglo;
                }
            }
            ?>

            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <title>WarenKorb</title>

                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
                <meta name="description" content="">

                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />


                <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
            </head>
            <body>

                <header>
                    <h1> Carrito de compras</h1>
                    <a href="./shoppingcar.php" title="ver carrito de compras">
                        <img src="">
                    </a>
                </header>


                <section>
                    <?php
                    $summe=0;
                    if(isset ($_SESSION['car'])){
                        $daten=$_SESSION['car'];

                        $summe=0;
                        for ($i=0; $i<count($daten); $i++) {


                            ?>

                            <div class="Produkt">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                                        <table class="table table-hover">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Produkt</th>
                                                    <th>Quantität</th>
                                                    <th class="text-center">Preis</th>
                                                    <th class="text-center">Summe</th>
                                                    <th> </th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="col-sm-8 col-md-6">
                                                        <div class="media">
                                                            <a class="thumbnail pull-left" href="#"> <img class="media-object" src="<?php echo $daten[$i]['foto'];?>" style="width: 72px; height: 72px;"> </a>
                                                            <div class="media-body">
                                                                <h4 class="media-heading"><a href="#"> <?php echo $daten[$i]['name']; ?></a></h4>
                                                                <h5 class="media-heading">  <a href="#"></a></h5>
                                                                <span>Status: </span><span class="text-success"><strong>In Stock</strong></span>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div></td>
                                                        <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1" style="text-align: center">
                                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="quantität" value="<?php echo $daten[$i]['menge'];?>">
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 text-center"><strong><?php echo "€" . number_format( $daten[$i]['preis'],2); ?></strong></td>
                                                        <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 text-center"><strong><?php echo $daten[$i]['menge']* $daten[$i]['preis'];?></strong></td>
                                                        <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1">
                                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
                                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Löschen
                                                            </button></td>
                                                        </tr>

                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>   </td>
                                                            <td>   </td>
                                                            <td>   </td>
                                                            <td><h5>Subtotal</h5></td>
                                                            <td class="text-right"><h5><strong><?php echo $daten[$i]['menge']*$daten[$i]['preis'];?></strong></h5></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>   </td>
                                                            <td>   </td>
                                                            <td>   </td>
                                                            <td><h5>Estimated shipping</h5></td>
                                                            <td class="text-right"><h5><strong>$6.94</strong></h5></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>   </td>
                                                            <td>   </td>
                                                            <td>   </td>
                                                            <td><h3>Total</h3></td>
                                                            <td class="text-right"><h3><strong><?php echo ($daten[$i]['menge']*$daten[$i]['preis'])+$summe;?></strong></h3></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>   </td>
                                                            <td>   </td>
                                                            <td>   </td>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Continue Shopping
                                                                </button></td>
                                                                <td>
                                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
                                                                        Checkout <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
                                                                    </button></td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>


                                            <?php
                                            $summe=($daten[$i]['menge']*$daten[$i]['preis'])+$summe;
                                        }
                                    }else {
                                        echo "<center><h2>El carro de compras esta vacio</h2></center>";
                                    }

                                    echo '<center><h2 id="Summe">Summe: '.$summe.'</h2></center>';
                                    if($summe!=0){
                                        echo '<center><a href="katalog.php" class="aceptar">Comprar</a></center>;';
                                    }
                                    ?>

                                </section>
                                <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
                                <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                            </body>
                            </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El primero error está en la línea donde intentas agregar el segundo producto:

```
array_push($datosNuevos,$arreglo);
```

Según la documentación de [`array_push`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-push.php), el primer parámetro es el arreglo en el cual se van a añadir los valores.

Si te fijas detenidamente esta agregando a `$datosNuevos` el arreglo `$arreglo` y el objetivo es hacer lo inverso.

El segundo error esta en la línea que se encuentra justo debajo de la anterior:

```
$_SESSION['Car']=$arreglo;
```

La posición en el arreglo es `car` (`c` minúscula), no `Car`.

### Soluciones:

Modificar dichas línea de la siguiente forma:

```
array_push($arreglo, $datosNuevos);
$_SESSION['car']=$arreglo;
```

**PD:** Te aconsejaria leer [este articulo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php) ya que tu codigo es susceptible a inyección SQL.

Comment: Gracias Marcos, he realizado el cambio que me recomendaste y sigo obteniendo el mismo resultado.

Comment: Lo que mas me confunde es que cuando se redirige a la otra pagina en la URL aparece el id del nuevo producto pero no lo agrega en la lista.

Comment: @Viatorii, he actualizado mi respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta Marcos, problema solucionado! Revisare tambien el articulo que me recomendaste.